# Identifying points in a curve

Tags: r, max, spline

I feel like this is an easy question...

How do you identify coordinates in a figure?  I plotted some data, used unireg (the uniReg package) to make a spline curve, and want to pull out the data from a point.

```
library(uniReg)
P0mM <- read.table(text="
Time           FeuM
0.04    138.8181818
   7    1258.636364
  14    1320.545455
  21     2110.37037
  28    13730.37037
  35    1550.909091",header=TRUE)

z=seq(min(P0mM$Time),max(P0mM$Time),length=201)
uf=with(P0mM,unireg(Time,FeuM,g=5,sigma=1))
plot(FeuM~Time,P0mM,ylim=c(0,16000),ylab="Fe2+ uM", xlab="Time", main="0mM P")
lines(z,uf$unimod.func(z))
```

[image]

I was able to find the max y value of the curve (which is 14444)

```
max((uf$unimod.func(z)))
```

I want to identify where on the x axis this happens.  (Should be around 30, but I want to be exact).

How do you do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want an "exact" answer then we need some "exact" data.

Comment: Could you provide your data (`P0mM`) using `dput`? Also, where does `unireg()` come from? Is it in some pacakge?

Comment: Also if you wnat your plot to look more scientific considre using arguemtns like these: `plot(1,1,ylim=c(0,16000),ylab=expression(Fe[2]^"+"~mu*M), xlab="Time", main="0 mMol P")`

Comment: I added data, and uniReg is the package.  At this point I'm not too interested in making it look professional, as I will likely tinker with it some more.  But thank you for the formatting code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a case for `optimise` or `optimize` (depending on your affinity with British or American English):

```
optimise(uf$unimod.func, maximum=TRUE, interval=range(P0mM$Time))
#$maximum
#[1] 29.27168
#
#$objective
#         [,1]
#[1,] 14444.85
```

Comment: Thank you!  I have a bunch of figures like this, and just tried them all.  It works for all of them.  I knew there was something simple!